# Issue with Email Alerts and Test.setMock - Uncommitted Work Pending

Tags: email-alert, httpcalloutmock

Seeing this error now if an object has an email alert on it during insert and using test.setMock

Disabling the workflow/process builder that contains the email alert and the test passes fine.

Test.setMock is inside or outside test.startTest() (does not matter). Test.starTest() and test.stopTest() enclose the code.

All triggered were disable and issue was narrowed down to the email alert workflows. At this point is seems to only be some email alerts and not all. I have not been able to narrow down what is different between the ones that cause the issue and the ones that do not.

Is this new or something that is known?

Code:

```
Account a = New Account();
    test.startTest();
        //Set Mock
        //Make Callout
     test.stopTest();
```

This causes the uncommitted work pending error.

Code above is about it. I added a field to the Account to check when creating records from test methods `Account a = New Account(DoNotSendEmailWorkflow = true);`and set the workflow rule to evaluate that and if checked do not do workflow.

When I do this test works just fine.

So, a workflow rule that sends an email alert will cause test methods using mock implementations to fail due to uncommitted work pending.

**Update 8-26-2016**

This issue is still happening as I just ran into it again.

**Update 10-25-2016**

now scheduled to be resolved in Winter 17 patch 12

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHBAA2

**UPDATE 11-04-2016**

SF has resolved this issue. I have not tested it out yet but they now say it was fixed in Winter '17 Patch 12.0

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHBAA2

Comment: Still happening. Anyone?

Comment: so -- you insert a test record, that triggers a workflow w/ email alert, then you `test.starttest - setMock() -testcode - test.stoptest()` ?  Might be clearer with a reduced set of your code

Comment: @crop1645 - See updated question. Yes basically it. Disable the rule, tests pass, enable the rule, tests fail. I narrowed it down by disabling ALL trigger and workflow rules and running test. Enable a single rule, run test, rinse and repeat. When I enabled the workflow rule that all it does is send an email alert, test failed with uncommitted work pending error.

Comment: note this known issue : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHBAA2 and somewhat related: http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/06/18/batchable-class-test-data-callouts-how-to-test/

Comment: @crop1645 - Thanks for finding the first link, I did not see that when I originally posted the issue (not sure if it was reported yet). The second link is well know. Been over a year now IIRC but i do not think it is related at all (or maybe it it) who knows....Either way, can you post the first link as an answer so I can close this question. I do not think there is anything else to be gained here as it is confirmed....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHBAA2) -- recently reported and contemporaneous with your OP

Comment: Resolved as of Winter '17 Patch 12.0

Answer (score -2):

I arrived here searching for answers to the same problem. You should contact Salesforce support and spend your text 4 weeks playing phone tag with them and trying to get escalated so they can become aware of this and fix the bug ;) I would, but I'm tired of that as I'm doing that with a few other issues right now and I feel like we're beta testers.

Anyways, one workaround I found is to wrap the email call in `if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {...}` so you can skip it during your test.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Skipping the test is NOT a good practice and serves no purpose. I ended up adding a checkbox to the objects and set it to true when the test is updating records. Then on the workflow rule that has email alerts, I set it to evaluate to false if the box is checked. That way my test can still run and fulfill their intended purpose of test our code...Oh, and I have no desire to contact support, it would be futile.....

Comment: I'm not saying to skip testing completely, for now I'm just saying to skip the email part as a temporary workaround.

Comment: You can;t skip the email part (Its a workflow email alert) unless you do what I outlined

Comment: Ah yes sorry about that, I read your description too quickly. I was having the exact same problem but Apex was sending the email.

Comment: This isn't even a valid answer so I'm downvoting it. As the issue reported here is workflow related.

Answer (score -3):

As per your flow discussed:

```
1. Insert Account
2. Call Test.startTest()
3. Set your mock
4. Make callout
5. Call Test.stopTest()
```

I solved this problem already by making `@isTest (seeAllData=true)` and queried the required Account record for my Callout purposes, the DML pending exception wasn't coming thereafter.

If the above doesn't work for you - (still giving pending DML exception / uncommitted work pending). You can try doing the Account insert inside of `System.runas` block.

Comment: @isTest (seeAllData=true) is not a good practice for writing tests.