# NO DML after Test.Start() but still getting System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending

Tags: unit-test, callout, httpcalloutmock

Basically, I'm getting the dreaded "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending." exception even though I'm 99.999% sure I'm not making any DML statements after running `Test.startTest()`.

I've reduced my test to the simplest form and am still getting the error.

```
 @isTest static void test_WTFSALESFORCE() {

    abc__c abc = new abc__c(
            Name = 'test'); 
    insert abc;

    //set mock
    MockHttpResponseGenerator mock = 
        new MockHttpResponseGenerator('http://google.com','Hello World');

    Test.startTest();

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://google.com');
    req.setMethod('GET');

    // Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    String resp = res.getBody();

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

*It is embarrassing how long I've spent trying to debug this with no progress...*

The object in question is a dummy object and not part of any workflows or triggers.

Am I missing something?

Also the test passes fine in a Full Copy Sandbox that was refreshed less than a month ago.

Comment: yes the issue may come from a trigger. First at least check triggers on account insert

Comment: @highfive There are tons of triggers and workflows.  The log for this simple piece of code is almost 6000 lines and that's with just at debug level.  I'm switching the DML to use a dummy object with no triggers or workflows to see if I still error out.

Comment: @highfive I tried the same test with a dummy blank object that is not being used anywhere. Same result

Comment: Try changing class version to 35. This code must work fine until there is no dml in between.

Comment: @Ashwani Holy Crap... I can't believe I didn't think of trying that :facepalm.  It was already running at v33 so I'm surprised made a difference.  Thanks you so much. Submit an answer just incase someone else runs across this wierdness?

Comment: @NSjonas pretty simple solution :) I have put this as answer as well so others can benefit.

Comment: Thank you... honestly I think this is the second time I've been tripped up by the API version.  Last time was long enough ago that I couldn't remember what I did to fix it.  Now that's it's officially on SE hopefully I remember next time.

Comment: Check email alerts http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71259/issue-with-email-alerts-and-test-setmock-uncommitted-work-pending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change API Version to 35. Version 35 doesn't have this issue.

Comment: seriously? what's the relation with that error and version number?

Comment: Changing the version solve many wierd behaviors. There can be chances that it has solved other related issue and that resolved the main issue. @highfive

Comment: Sooo... it seems to get my simplest use case to pass but once I added back the real world test it's failing again...   I give up.   No test is worth this amount of effort

Comment: @NSjone You will have to look end to end to see where the DML is happening. The code you have posted should run without any exceptions.

Comment: Else you can use a workaround. Use `Test.isRunningTest` and skip `http.send(req)` in main code.

Comment: yea.. I'm going to go back to what's passing and start working back towards the real test.  See if I can't pin point exactly what is causing the issue.  At this point, I would have been better of just refactoring the code to be testable without the DML setup (as i should have in the first place), but everything has already gone through QA and I don't want to make any potentially breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out another reason this might be happening is if you have a workflow that with an `Email Alert` action.  You can easily see if this is happening by searching your debug log for an event of: `WF_EMAIL_ALERT`.

I had a project where I couldn't seem to test ANY callout, no matter how simple the setup.  Turns out the Account had a workflow on it that sent an email alert if a field was blank.  Of course my `TestUtil` method that was instantiating accounts wasn't setting this field.

Comment: Yup. I reported it back in April last year http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71259/issue-with-email-alerts-and-test-setmock-uncommitted-work-pending and it is still present

Comment: @Eric really wish I had come across your post back then..  Could have saved me many hours of frustration