# Unit test error - You have uncommitted work pending

Tags: callout, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock

I get an error in my apex test class

`You have uncommitted work pending`

I am aware of the Salesforce limitation in an http callout, we can't perform any DML operations before we send an http callout.

So, I tried to put the DML in the rest web service (*its a little trick but works fine*), but the problem is that I still get the same error in my test class.

Code example as follows:

> ***1.Business Logic***
>
> - lock status
> - send http request
> - free status

```
public class B1 {
    public void foo() {
        Locker__c lk = [SELECT Id,Status__c FROM Locker__c WHERE ...];
        lk.Status__c = 'unavailable';
        UPDATE lk;
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(out_webservice_api_url);
        ......
        h.send(req);//it would be throw a error with uncommitted work pending
        lk.Status__c = 'available';
        UPDATE lk;
    }
}
```

> ***2.Rest Api Code***

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/internal/update_lock')
public class UpdateLock {
    public static void doPost(Locker__c lk) {
        UPDATE lk;
    }
}
```

> ***3.Business Code***

```
public class B2 {
    public void foo() {
        Locker__c lk = [SELECT Id,Status__c FROM Locker__c WHERE ...];
        lk.Status__c = 'unavailable';
        String endpoint = 'instance_url/services/apexrest/internal/update_lock/';
        //lock
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(JSON.serialize(lk));
        .......
        h.send(req);
        req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(out_webservice_api_url);
        .....
        h.send(req);
        lk.status__c='avaliable';
        UPDATE lk;
    }
```

> ***4.test mock class***

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData = false)
global class MyCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        Locker__c lk = (Locker__c)JSON.deserialize(req.getBody(), Locker__c.class);
        UpdateLock.doPost(lk);
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

> ***5.test class***

```
@isTest
private class B2Test {
    @isTest
    static void unitTest() {
        //
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyCalloutMock());
        B2 b = new B2();
        b.foo();//throw a error
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @FJony you can refer this link: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126617/system-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending-during-test-for-callo/126621#126621

Comment: You are performing an update in b2 and thus cannot make a callout in b.foo in same transaction.

Comment: @Eric No,error occurs in the second callout cause first internal callout has performed a dml operations to update locker status in mock class.

Comment: U r correct. I read your naming convention wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code:

```
@isTest
private class B2Test {
    @isTest
    static void unitTest() {
        //
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyCalloutMock());
        Test.startTest();
        B2 b = new B2();
        b.foo();//throw a error
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Your issue is already pointed out in previous comments. And the above code will probably resolve your issue by separating them into different contexts via start and stop test.

Comment: Its also appears same error even move Test.startTest() behind to the SetMock method.